# How do you create a layout in Android Studio with image view, and 25 text views?

Tags: android, android-layout

so I am a programmer and have gotten the functionality of my app working, and I have all the elements of my layout in place and working, but not layed out the way i would like to have them layed out.  I have been fighting with Android Studio to get the layout I want.

ImageView center top of screen
TextView with some padding bleow it center across the whole screen.
3x7 Tabel Layout under the TextView with some padding between the table layout and text view.

I keep trying and am getting frustrated because I don't do layouts.

Any and all help is appreciative.

I have tried using linear, Relative and table layouts.  I might get one thing right but don't know how to adjust for the others without messing something else up.

I don't have any code because, what I have done doesn't work and thought that maybe someone could help me out and provide me the layout described above.

With the help of Joan Sanchez this is what I have:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is a place Holder"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Normal Hours Of Operation" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Day Of Week"/>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Open Time"/>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Closing Time"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Monday"/>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="11:00 A.M."/>
    .
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 P.M."/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Tuesday"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 A.M."/>
        .....
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 P.M."/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Wednesday"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 A.M."/>
        .....
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 P.M."/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Thursday"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 A.M."/>
        .....
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 P.M."/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Friday"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 A.M."/>
        .....
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 P.M."/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Saturday"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 A.M."/>
        .....
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="11:00 P.M."/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sunday"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CLOSED"/>
        .....
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CLOSED"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>`
```

So what I am trying to do now is move the the linearlayout that has the Hours Of Operation and te rest below to be bottom weight, right above my bottom nav bar.  Make my image larger left to right, and then move the textViewStatus down a little bit further below the image.  I do want to increase the font size and change it, again not sure of the parameters to do it.  Font type to like Arial Black and unsure of size.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I have understood correctly what you are asking for, but hope this helps:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp" 
    android:src="@drawable/test"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="hello"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="test1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="test2"/>
         ....
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="test7"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="test1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="test2"/>
       .....
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="test7"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="test1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="test2"/>
        ......
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="test7"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The weight = 1 will make all your cells same size.
Hope it helps!

Comment: So I edited my original question to add the xml that I am using now with the help of Joan Sanchez as it does exactly what i need it to do.  There is just a spacing issue which I mentioned as well in the updated original question as well.

Comment: So I figure I would try using a frame layout around all the linear layouts from Hours of operations all the way down to Sundays closed closed and gave it a gravity of bottom and that still did not do the trick.  Now I did do this inside of the main linear layout.

Comment: Okay got font color and sizes working, come to find out that adding a custom font is more involved than I have time for so I will deal with what is currently available.  so the only issue that remains is how do I move everything from HOURS OF OPERATION down, to the bottom of the screen or put more space inbetween to push it down.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone.  This is now completely solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try having your Layout with multiple rows(textview and image view) in Vertical ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, I think you can insert blank layout after your textview place holder like below.set the layout weight to 1, so that it consumes all the remaining space. hope it helps.

```
    <!--add free space-->
       <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
```